# Mapping database structure from SQL Server to DynamoDB

Tags: sql-server, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am thinking about using a NoSQL database to scale database reads.  Please see the relational database structure below:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
      ID uniqueidentifier not null, 
      Name varchar(100), 
      DateOfBirth datetime)

CREATE TABLE Sport (
      ID uniqueidentifier not null, 
      Description varchar(50)) -- e.g. Football; Tennis; Badminton etc

CREATE TABLE PersonPlaysSport (
      PersonID uniqueidentifier FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Person(ID), 
      SportID uniqueidentifier FOREIGN KEY REFERENCE Sport (ID), 
      primary key (PersonID, SportID)
```

In the example above a Person Plays many Sports.  In my real application; I have many-to-many relationships like this that do not perform well.

How would these be stored in a NoSQL document database (DynamoDB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer - I'm not familiar with `DynamoDb`, but have used several other NoSql databases*

The common approach is to choose the most important subject entity as the `root` of the document (in your case, I would say this is `Person`)

A document is then created for each person, and will include the "person centric" view of all associated entities (i.e. linked sports):

```
Joe (Person, Keyed on a natural, or surrogate id).
+ Fields of Joe (Date of Birth, etc)
+ SportsPlayed: (Collection)
--> Golf (Sport)
--> Tennis (Sport)
```

If it becomes important to view the relationship from a Sport centric approach (e.g. you need to know which persons are 'subscribed' to which Sport):

- You could attempt a secondary index on `Person.Sport`, if the NoSql database allows this. This would allow for queries like "Who plays Golf?", although this approach is often frowned upon in NoSql terms.
- Alternatively, and preferably, create a second collection of documents, this time keyed by `Sport`:

```
Golf (Sport)
- Joe
- Jim
...
```

etc. Obviously there's extra work to be done in keeping both sets of documents up to date when a change is made to a `Person`, a `Sport`, or the relationship between them, however the benefit is high performance on the read side - only a single document needs to be retrieved to pull the entire entity graph - In SQL terms, this would have required a Query joining 3 distinct tables.

Comment: Thanks.  How would you synchronise SQL Server with the NoSQL database? I was thinking about doing something like this: http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/05/06/combining-sql-server-and-mongodb-using-nhibernate/ i.e. using EventListeners and Interceptors in NHibernate.  However, I wandered if there was a better way.

Comment: Also, may I ask if there is a specific reason that you have avoided DynamoDb?

Comment: We haven't avoided Dynamo - it's just that we're using mostly On Premise DB's like MongoDB, Riak, Aerospike, and lately Cassandra. For cloud hosted NoSql's I use are the Azure ones - e.g. TableStorage, and DocumentDb. If you've already got most of your `master` data in relational databases, instead of changing your apps / procs, you might try and use a reactive streaming approach to data synchronization, e.g. around [Sql Broker Notification Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker).

Comment: Thanks.  What do you think of the approach described in my link.  I am using NHibernate as the ORM.  However, I could switch to Entity Framework.  This is more of a learning exercise in my free time.

Comment: I've no doubt that it would work just fine. If you've already wrapped data access in an `IRepository` type layer, you could also use e.g. the decorator pattern to build a `combo` repository to keep things synchronized. The other common approach in this space is via Event Driven Architecture using a Service Bus  - e.g. Whenever the system owning 'Person' data changes a Person, it could publish a message to the bus with the new Person data, and other interested systems (such as NoSql-backed User Interfaces) could then subscribe, shape, and store the data the way it is needed.

Comment: Thanks.  Are your approaches ('combo repository' and 'Service Bus' explained in more detail somewhere (that you are aware of)? Does the link I posted in my first comment explain one of these approaches?

Comment: I think I'm overcomplicating things, and we're way off topic for your original question. First, I would suggest you just get to grips with Dynamo and the 'different style of thinking' typically needed for NoSql databases if you've spent a large amount of time on relational (Sql) databases. Use the most simple (and direct) way of updating your NoSql 'read stores' that you can think of, and you can always get fancy with Reactive, Event Driven or Bus-based approaches much later. Enjoy!

Comment: If you could answer my question here from yesterday then I would be grateful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099152/what-is-a-combo-repository-and-a-service-bus.  I have improved my knowledge over the last few days, however I am still unsure what you mean.  Thanks.